# Unreadable mail in Outlook, sent from iPad

Tags: outlook-on-the-web

Today I received an email from a client. She is using an iPad to send the mail, but I'm receiving it as an unreadable mail.

The translated error message is `This message has a structure that cannot be displayed`.

And the Content-Type is `multipart/alternative`.

I'm using the Outlook web client. What can I do to display the mail?

Comment: @pnuts I have access to the source. But the message that should be there is replaced by the error message.

Comment: @pnuts here is a pastebin of the mail: http://pastebin.com/jukQiveA

. I have replaced all sensitive information (names, email addresses, etc) though.

Comment: @pnuts Since it's a forwarded message, I've asked the original author to send me a copy of the mail directly. Maybe that'll solve the issue. Thanks anyway!

Comment: @pnuts I got the mail directly now. There was a pdf in the attachment. I assume something went wrong when receiving or sending the mail on the iPad.